# Remove currency symbol from price

Tags: javascript, regex

The price are render like this on my website : 20$US , how can I remove the US symbol and keep the $ symbol with regex (JavaScrip) ?

I would like the price to be render like this :20$

I have tried this :

```
<script>

$.each($('.price'), function() {
var pri = $(this).html();
$(this).html(pri.replace(/\D/g,''));
} )

</script>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you attempt to solve this problem by yourself?

Comment: Yes, This is what I have tried:     `<script>

    $.each($('.price'), function() {
    var pri = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(pri.replace(/\D/g,''));
    } )

    </script>`

Comment: You should **always** post your code in the question, this way we can see what you've tried already and it's easier to help.

Comment: It is also good to describe how your approach fails, what do you get after running your code? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `replace` method which accepts as first parameter a `regex` expression.

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of
>   a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a
>   `RegExp`, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called
>   for each match.

```js
let string='20$US';
let desired = string.replace(/US/gi, '');
console.log(desired);
```

Comment: Using `let` and `var` together sounds like bad codestyle.

Comment: @Olga, in this example yes, but in real application not. `let` is a solution for `closures`.`let` in used specially for enclosed block scope.

Comment: `closures` are not a problem they are a language feature, so I don't see how you can solve them. Using let and var together defeats the purpose of let, const, which is to be block scoped and throw errors when used before defined. But I guess this may turn into a long off-topic holy war conversation. =)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai , I have tried with your example and it seem like it's working perfectly . Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Modern solution to parse any currency into number:

```js
import currencyToFloat from 'currency-to-float';

const price = '20.50$US';

const parsed = currencyToFloat(price);

console.log(parsed); // 20.5
```